# Generic Data Type Parameter

Tags: java, arrays, generics, parameters

I have this class which deals with sorting arrays via `selectionSort`. . .I am having trouble sorting my array in my main function (attached at the bottom)...What is the correct way of calling `selctionSort()`?

My problem: "The method `selectionSort(T[], int)` in the type `SortArray` is not applicable for the arguments `(int[], int)`" ... I'm trying to pass my int array to the function, which keeps giving me this error.

```
/**
   Class for sorting an array of Comparable objects from smallest to 
   largest.
*/
public class SortArray
{
   /** Sorts the first n objects in an array into ascending order.
       @param a  an array of Comparable objects
       @param n  an integer > 0 */
   public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void selectionSort(T[] a, int n)
   {
      for (int index = 0; index < n - 1; index++)
      {
         int indexOfNextSmallest = getIndexOfSmallest(a, index, n - 1);
         swap(a, index, indexOfNextSmallest);
         // Assertion: a[0] <= a[1] <= . . . <= a[index] <= all other a[i]
      } // end for
   } // end selectionSort

   /** Finds the index of the smallest value in a portion of an array.
       @param a      an array of Comparable objects
       @param first  an integer >= 0 and < a.length that is the index of 
                     the first array entry to consider
       @param last   an integer >= first and < a.length that is the index 
                     of the last array entry to consider
       @return the index of the smallest value among
               a[first], a[first + 1], . . . , a[last] */
   private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
           int getIndexOfSmallest(T[] a, int first, int last)
   {
      T min = a[first];
      int indexOfMin = first;
      for (int index = first + 1; index <= last; index++)
      {
         if (a[index].compareTo(min) < 0)
         {
            min = a[index];
            indexOfMin = index;
         } // end if
         // Assertion: min is the smallest of a[first] through a[index].
      } // end for

      return indexOfMin;
   } // end getIndexOfSmallest

   /** Swaps the array entries a[i] and a[j].
       @param a  an array of objects
       @param i  an integer >= 0 and < a.length
       @param j  an integer >= 0 and < a.length */
   private static void swap(Object[] a, int i, int j)
   {
      Object temp = a[i];
      a[i] = a[j];
      a[j] = temp; 
   } // end swap
} // end SortArray


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] anArray = {15, 8, 10, 2, 5};          // given array

    System.out.println("Printing unsorted array...");
    for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
        System.out.print(anArray[i] + " ");

    SortArray.selectionSort(anArray, anArray.length);

    System.out.println("\nPrinting sorted array...");
}
```

Comment: When you say "I am having trouble...", what exactly do you mean? This doesn't give us much information with which we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your method expects an array of Objects not an array of primitives. So an int[] won't work, but Integer[] will work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // int[] anArray = {15, 8, 10, 2, 5}; // given array
  Integer[] anArray = { 15, 8, 10, 2, 5 }; // given array

  System.out.println("Printing unsorted array...");
  for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
     System.out.print(anArray[i] + " ");

  SortArray.selectionSort(anArray, anArray.length);

  System.out.println("\nPrinting sorted array...");
  for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
     System.out.print(anArray[i] + " ");

}
```

Edit: actually, it expects more than an array of Object. They also have to implement the Comparable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely to your declaration:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void selectionSort(T[] a, int n)
```

`T` needs to be a type that extends `Comparable`.

When you are using it:

```
SortArray.selectionSort(anArray, anArray.length);
```

first parameter is of type `int[]`, and `int` is not fulfilling this requirement for `T`.

Instead of passing in `int[]`, you may consider passing in an `Integer[]`.  `Integer` itself implements `Comparable`, and you don't need to change a lot of your code in order to switch using that.  Simply change the declaration of `anArray` from `int[]` to `Integer[]` will probably work already.